# TortoiseSVN: show file in a previous revision?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, revision

Let's say I have 4 revisions.

Is there a way to see the file how it was on revision 2 for example? I can't find an option to open older revision in TortoiseMerge

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use "Show Log" on a file to view the revisions, there you can open an old one...

Answer (score -1):

you have to install

win merge

http://garr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/winmerge/stable/2.12.4/WinMerge-2.12.4-Setup.exe

and it will be integrated with tortoisesvn auto matically
then you can diff file with the current one to see the changes